# Plotting an implicit polar equation

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

*Mathematica* can use `ContourPlot` to draw implicit Cartesian equations, but doesn't seem to have a similar function to plot an implicit polar equation, for example

$\theta ^2=\left(\frac{3 \pi }{4}\right)^2 \cos (r)$

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Well, it's a good question and I see solutions people are coming up with are different. Always interesting to see and compare, no harm in it.

Comment: @David can I ask why you removed the "storytelling paragraph"? I only wanted to let people know that I planned to answer myself, and would have deleted it myself later.

Comment: We don't want to discourage people from answering questions.  Even if you have one solution, there might be others that are enlightening for yourself or others.

Comment: Makes sense, I just didn't want to make others spend their time repeating a solution I already have written out. Nevermind, as you said, all contributions are helpful.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67261/1871

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since `ContourPlot[]` returns a `GraphicsComplex`, you could also replace the point list of the plot with `g @@@ pointlist` where `g` is the coordinate transformation. For example

```
f[r_, th_] := th^2 - (3 Pi/4)^2 Cos[r]
g[r_, th_] := {r Cos[th], r Sin[th]} 

pl = ContourPlot[f[r, th] == 0, {r, 0, 8 Pi}, {th, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 30];
pl[[1, 1]] = g @@@ pl[[1, 1]];

Show[pl, PlotRange -> All]
```

which produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The advantage of this method is that it also works for coordinate transformations for which the inverse transformation is hard to find.

Comment: cheeky, cheeky... +1

Comment: Very interesting point, applying the coordinate transformation to the finished plot. However, I think this might fail for high frequency functions/coordinate systems etc., since after plotting things like the step distance between points are already set.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing, I turned it into a self-contained function so I'll post it up later. +1 for reading my mind.
@David I did find that quality was reduced but bumping up MaxRecursions helps without slowing things down too much.

Comment: I would include `AspectRatio -> Automatic` in `Show` so that this "looks nice."

Comment: It doesn't work in version 13. It should be `pl[[1, 1, 1]] = g @@@ pl[[1, 1, 1]];`

Answer (score 13):

Does this

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@With[
   {r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2],
    θ = ArcTan[x, y]},
   θ^2 - Cos[r] == 0
   ],
 {x, 0.1, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}
 ]
```

work?

Plot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is a great method, unfortunately it's not as useful if you want to specify the plotting range in polar, rather than cartesian, coordinates. +1 for your `ContourPlot` substitution, this is something I tried originally but couldn't get to work.

Comment: @myk thanks, Heike's is definitely cleverer and also more useful if you can't invert the transformation easily

Answer (score 10):

If you allow negative radii, there's another entire half of the solution:

```
PolarPlot[
   Evaluate[Flatten[
      Table[{-ArcCos[(16 t^2)/(9 Pi^2)], ArcCos[(16 t^2)/(9 Pi^2)]} + k 2 Pi, 
            {k, -2, 2}]
      ]], 
   {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Table[Directive[Thick, Hue[i/10]], {i, 10}]
   ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like this:

```
ContourPlot[ArcTan[x,y]^2 == (3 Pi/4)^2 Cos[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], 
{x, -23, 23}, {y, -23, 23}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Orange]]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you're still missing a square on the 3Pi/4.

Comment: @BrettChampion Yes, thanks, have to get my math straight ;-)

Answer (score 8):

All the other three solutions use `ContourPlot`. Here's a solution using `PolarPlot`.

```
PolarPlot[{ArcCos[#2^2/(3 π/4)^2] + 2 π #1, 
    -ArcCos[#2^2/(3 π/4)^2] + 2 π (#1 + 1)} & @@ QuotientRemainder[Abs@ θ, 2 π], 
    {θ, -7 π, 8 π}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Darker@Green}]
```

[image]

This makes use of the fact that the solution to $\theta^2=\displaystyle\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)^2\cos(r)$ is

$$r=\pm\arccos\left(\frac{16\theta^2}{9\pi^2}\right)+2\pi n,\ n\in\mathbb{Z}$$