# How to plot an ellipse?

Tags: plotting

I'm new to *Mathematica*, and I'm finding it difficult to plot an ellipse. 
I tried using

```
Plot[(x/5)^2 + (y/3)^2 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

but I'm getting some errors. Is there something wrong with the syntax? Or do I need to rewrite the equation and plot?

Comment: "`Plot` generates a plot of f as a function of x from xmin to xmax". So you're using too many variables.

Comment: Closely related: [Coloring a shape according to a function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26895/coloring-a-shape-according-to-a-function/26900#26900)

Comment: Related: [(547)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/547/121), [(5968)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5968/121)

Answer (score 33):

Even though Mr. Wizard's answer plus comments give the most generalizable answers, the closest to what the *original question* was doing is probably this:

```
Plot[y /. Solve[(x/5)^2 + (y/3)^2 == 1], {x, -5, 5}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: solve plot]

The ability to plot two branches of a solution as a single curve is sometimes cited as one of the advantages of the fact that `Plot` doesn't automatically evaluate its arguments due to its `HoldAll` attribute (which in other situations causes confusion when you try to plot lists of functions in different colors). Here we want both branches of the square root to appear in the same plot style, and this is automatically recognized. If I had forced the `Solve` output to be evaluated too early, this plot wouldn't work.

Answer (score 22):

Please see this reference:  [How To | Create Plots](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CreatePlots.html).

You need [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourPlot.html) for that implicitly defined function.
You will also need `AspectRatio -> Automatic` if you want it to *look* like an ellipse and not a circle.

```
ContourPlot[(x/5)^2 + (y/3)^2 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3, 3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you merely want to display an ellipse use `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, {5, 3}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that `AspectRatio -> Automatic` was not needed; it is the default for `Graphics`, whereas plot functions default to `1/GoldenRatio`.

---

[Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens) showed a use of `Plot` (which I voted for) that illustrates styling two solutions to an equation the same.  This *is* useful, but it is also inefficient as we call `Solve` again and again.  Alternatives are manually specifying the `PlotStyle`:

```
sols = y /. Solve[(x/5)^2 + (y/3)^2 == 1, y];

Plot[sols, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Blue, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

And using `Sequence` to group the elements as I described in [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/difference-in-plot-when-using-evaluate-vs-when-not-using-evaluate/1735#1735):

```
Plot[Sequence @@ sols, {x, -5, 5}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Another way:`ParametricPlot[{ 5 Cos[t], 3 Sin[t]}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]`

Comment: Perhaps this, too: `RegionPlot[Abs[(x/5)^2 + (y/3)^2 - 1] < .1, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 80]`

Answer (score 8):

```
ParametricPlot[{2*Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use the [`Ellipsoid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid.html) graphics primitive:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {5, 3}]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `RegionPlot[]` (for 2D shapes) or `ContourPlot[]` (for 1D boundaries):

```
ContourPlot[(x/5)^2 + (y/3)^2 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to set `AspectRatio -> Automatic` for this.

Comment: It seems to me that the `ContourPlot` approach was covered previously in [Mr.Wizard's answer to this very question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20101/27951), which also included the necessary `AspectRatio` adjustment already suggested by @J.M. . Perhaps you could expand on your answer to differentiate the two; otherwise this seems a duplicate of his answer to me.

Comment: ISTM the earlier answer had too many alternatives and elaborations listed.  I didn't even see it mentioning ContourPlot the first times I scrolled through it.