# Plotting an ellipse given axial ratio and orientation

Tags: plotting

I have already looked at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20100/how-to-plot-an-ellipse) answer but couldn't figure out how to use it in my case, particularly due to needing to include the orientation. I currently have a value for my axial ratio and a value for my orientation, and that is all. The size is irrelevant due to prior normalization. I feel like I am just missing something in the other question, but don't know what it is, this kind of math isn't my forte. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "a value for my orientation" - by this, you mean the angle of the major axis from the horizontal?

Comment: Yes, that is what I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = 5; b = 3;
ϕ = π/6;
ParametricPlot[{a Cos[t] Cos[ϕ] - b Sin[t] Sin[ϕ], 
a Cos[t] Sin[ϕ] + b Sin[t] Cos[ϕ]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]
```

[image]