# Plotting in polar coordinates, simple implicit curves

Tags: coordinate-transformation, plotting

How can I plot  $\theta=\cos r$ in polar plane? Of course I know that it is different from $r=\cos \theta.$

Comment: does this work: PolarPlot[ArcCos[t], {t, -Pi, Pi}]?

Comment: `ContourPlot[θ == Cos[r], {r, 0, 50}, {θ, -π, π},
  MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{r_Real, t_Real} :> {r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}]]`  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/300018/72111

Answer (score 13):

- If you can transform it to a parametric form:

  ```
  ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate @ CoordinateTransform["Polar" -> "Cartesian", {r, Cos[r]}], 
    {r, 0, 50}
  ]
  ```

  [image]
- And if you have to use implicit form:

  ```
  ContourPlot[
      Evaluate[
          TransformedField[
              "Polar" -> "Cartesian", θ == Cos[r], {r, θ} -> {x, y}
          ] 
      ]
    , {x, 0, 50}
    , {y, -50, 50}
    , PlotPoints -> 25
    , AspectRatio -> Automatic
    , Frame -> False, Axes -> True
   ]
  ```

  [image]

Answer (score 7):

Does this work for you:

```
PolarPlot[{ArcCos[t], -ArcCos[t]}, {t, -1,1}]
```

[image]

**Update:**      (*Sjoerd C. de Vries  comment*)

For all r

```
r=(+/-)ArcCos[t]+2 n Pi
```

Taking few of r results:

```
Show[Table[
  PolarPlot[{ArcCos[t], -ArcCos[t]} + n 2 Pi, {t, -1, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All], {n, -10, 10}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Let $\theta$ is arbitrary, How is the graph?

Comment: I don't understand you. but in general for each theta you will find r using ArcCos[theta]. then {theta,r} will be a point in the plot.

Comment: I suppose you should take into account that r is unrestricted, so you have to work with Mod 2 pi.

Comment: Why is left side included? theta is Cos[r] so in <-1,1> interval, right?

Comment: for each theta we can have r and -r. check this: Reduce[theta == Cos[r], r].

Comment: That's probably kind of academic discussion but there is Cos[r] and r is > 0, if you assume that r can be negative, then ok.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution is to

1. `ContourPlot` the equation directly;
2. Make the coordinate transform on the coordinates of points inside the resulting graphic.

I've wrapped these steps in a function:

```
ClearAll@implicitPlot
implicitPlot[eq_, range__, coordSys_, opt : OptionsPattern[ContourPlot]] := 
 Module[{coord}, 
  With[{plot = ContourPlot[eq, range, opt, PlotRange -> All], 
    trans = #[coord, #2] &[Function, 
       CoordinateTransform[coordSys -> "Cartesian", {coord[1], coord[2]}]] /. 
      coord[i_] :> Part[coord, i]}, 
   plot /. GraphicsComplex[coord_, rest_] :> 
     GraphicsComplex[trans[coord\[Transpose]]\[Transpose], rest]]]

implicitPlot[Cos@r == theta, {r, 0, 40}, {theta, -8 Pi, 8 Pi}, "Polar", 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The advantage of this approach is, it allows us to directly set domain of definition under the interested coordinate system.

Answer (score 3):

for completeness this can be done with `ContourPlot` (solutions already given are faster and probably better quality)

```
ContourPlot[
 Cos[Norm[{x, y}]] - ArcTan[x, y] == 0, {x, 0, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]