# plotting a function in bipolar coordinates

Tags: plotting

How to plot a function specified in bipolar coordinates if straightforward substitution of expression of Cartesian ones via them is impossible?

Comment: "a function specified in bipolar coordinates" - do you have an example on hand?

Comment: Analogous solution should work: [graph in the Polar Plane](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67275/5478)

Comment: Yes, the function I wish to see is  
Sqrt[Cosh[u] - Cos[v]]/Sinh[u] \!\(
\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(f\), \(\(-1\)/2\), \(,\)]\)[\(Cosh[u]\)]\)
where Subscript[f, -1/2] is Legendre' s either P or Q of order - 
 1/2 of imaginary argument. Too complcated for a beginner.

Comment: you should edit the question with your function.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by implementing the transformation formula directly:
(ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_coordinates )

```
bipolar[a_] =  a {Sinh[#[[2]]], Sin[#[[1]]]}/
                     (-Cos[#[[1]]] + Cosh[#[[2]]]) &

Show[{ParametricPlot[ 
   Table[bipolar[1]@{s, t}, {t, 
     Cases[Range[-3, 3], Except[0]]}] , {s, -Pi, Pi}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All],
  ParametricPlot[ 
   Table[bipolar[1]@{s, t}, {s, 
     Cases[Range[-3, 3], Except[0]]}] , {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image]

or use the built in `CoordinateTransform`

```
ParametricPlot[ 
   Evaluate[ CoordinateTransform[
         {{"Bipolar", {1}} -> "Cartesian"}, {s, 1}]] ,
            {s, -Pi, Pi}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]]
```

(note `Evaluate` is essential here or it will be extremely slow)

Comment: Thank you very much. I try to understand what is written.