# Plot in polar coordinates

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the next parametric curves in polar coordinates

```
r(t)=sin(r(t))
phi(t)=t
```

How can I make it in Mathematica?

Comment: Is this what you need [67261](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67261/5478)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
r[t_] = Sin[t];
PolarPlot[r[t], {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

Comment: It's essential, that the curve is implicitly defined.That is, something like ContourPlot should work here.

Comment: @ArtemZefirov That should be part of the question. Your example is too simple.