# Equipotential surfaces using ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, function-construction, parametric-functions, mesh

So I'm trying to plot lines on which the following function is a constant
$$
\frac{\left(-\Sigma (r,0.99,\theta )+2 r^2-0.99^2 r \sin ^2(\theta )\right)^2}{\Delta (r,1,0.99) \Sigma (r,0.99,\theta )^3}+\frac{0.99^4 \sin ^2(\theta ) \cos ^2(\theta ) \Delta (r,1,0.99)}{\Sigma (r,0.99,\theta )^4}
$$
where $$\Delta (r,M,a):=a^2-2 M r+r^2\quad\text{and}\quad\Sigma (r,a,\theta):=a^2 \cos ^2(\theta )+r^2.
$$
I'm using the following code which was motivated from the second comment on [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203867/polar-contour-plot-in-mathematica)

```
Σ[r_, a_, θ_] := r^2 + a^2*Cos[θ]^2;
Δ[r_, M_, a_] := r^2 - 2 M r + a^2;
cValues = 
   {0.01, 0.1, 0.08, 0.06, 0.003, 0.005, 0.12, 0.14, 0.2, 0.15, 0.02, 0.04, 
    0.03, 0.18, 0.22, 1.5, 2.3, 0.002, 0.0025, 0.003, 0.0015, 0.0018, 0.0023, 
    0.0011, 0.0009, 0.0008, 0.0007, 0.0006, 0.0005};
trajectories = 
  Function[{x, y, r, θ},  
    Σ[r, 0.99, θ]^(-3)*Δ[r, 1, 0.99]^(-1)*(2 r^2 - 
    Σ[r, 0.99, θ] - 0.99^2 r Sin[θ]^2)^2 + 
    Δ[r, 1, 0.99]*0.99^4*Σ[r, 0.99, θ]^(-4) Sin[θ]^2 Cos[θ]^2];
ParametricPlot[{Sqrt[r^2 + 0.99^2]*Sin[θ], r Cos[θ]}, {r, 0, 5}, {θ, 0, Pi/2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green}, MeshFunctions -> {trajectories}, Mesh -> {cValues}]
```

and it gives the output as shown here (the second one is the zoomed out version of the first).

[image][image]

As you can see, the bottom left corner has strange behavior and I'm not sure why. I also do not understand what the `trajectories` part of this code is doing, more  precisely why does the `Function` have 4 arguments in the beginning? Please help.

(context: I'm trying to plot the lines of constant acceleration in Kerr spacetime)

Comment: increasing the `PlotPoints -> 100`

Comment: These "strange" trajectories are no artefact. They are real, created by cValues = {1.5, 2.3}; It would be interesting to know what it means in physics.

Comment: The "anomalies" would be smoother if you add the options `PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5` to the `ParametricPlot`. This would of course slow down the computation for the plot.

Comment: Thanks! the `PlotPoints` did the trick, it is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html)
is a powerful method which I always use.

Here we view the `Mesh` from 3D. So we draw the `ParametricPlot3D`
$$\begin{cases}x=\sqrt{r^2+0.9801} \sin (\theta ),\\ 
y=r \cos (\theta ),\\
z=f(r,\theta)\end{cases}$$

We set the `ViewPoint={0,0,Infinity}`  and use `ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"`

```
Clear["`*"];
Σ[r_, a_, θ_] = r^2 + a^2*Cos[θ]^2;
Δ[r_, M_, a_] = r^2 - 2 M r + a^2;
f[r_, θ_] = Σ[r, 
      0.99, θ]^(-3)*Δ[r, 1, 
      0.99]^(-1)*(2 r^2 - Σ[r, 0.99, θ] - 
       0.99^2 r Sin[θ]^2)^2 + Δ[r, 1, 
     0.99]*0.99^4*Σ[r, 
      0.99, θ]^(-4) Sin[θ]^2 Cos[θ]^2;
cValues = {0.01, 0.1, 0.08, 0.06, 0.003, 0.005, 0.12, 0.14, 0.2, 0.15,
    0.02, 0.04, 0.03, 0.18, 0.22, 1.5, 2.3, 0.002, 0.0025, 0.003, 
   0.0015, 0.0018, 0.0023, 0.0011, 0.0009, 0.0008, 0.0007, 0.0006, 
   0.0005};
ParametricPlot3D[{Sqrt[r^2 + 0.99^2]*Sin[θ], r Cos[θ], 
  f[r, θ]}, {r, 0, 5}, {θ, 0, π/2}, 
 PlotPoints -> 150, MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> {cValues}, 
 PlotStyle -> Green, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}, Lighting -> {White, "Neutral"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your question as to why `trajectories` has four arguments:
`MeshFunctions` for `ParametricPlot` need three to four arguments. The first two correspond to the coordinates of the plot, the last two (or one) to the parameters of the `ParametricPlot`.

To appreciate this better, consider the following example:

```
funs = {
   Function[{x, y, u, v}, x],
   Function[{x, y, u, v}, y],
   Function[{x, y, u, v}, u],
   Function[{x, y, u, v}, v]
   };
Row@Table[ParametricPlot[
   {r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]]},
   {r, 0, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]/2},
   MeshFunctions -> fun,
   Mesh -> 10,
   ImageSize -> Small
   ], {fun, funs}
  ]
```

[image: Illustration of the usage of MeshFunctions.]

Comment: Since the original code is `{Sqrt[r^2 + 0.99^2]*Sin[\[Theta]], r Cos[\[Theta]]}` instead of  `r*Sin[\[Theta]],r Cos[\[Theta]]}` , so it is not a polar coordinate.

Comment: OK, I guess actually the `ParametricPlot` hack is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

@Natas, the thing is with this question that equipotentials are not plotted in polar coordinates, they are plotted in some special coordinates similar to polar coordinates (take a look at the first argument in ParametricPlot, "ParametricPlot[{Sqrt[r^2 + 0.99^2]*Sin[[Theta]], r Cos[[Theta]]},..."). That is why ParametricPlot way was used instead of ContourPlot, it allows you to use user defined coordinates that are not built-in in Mathematica. With polar coordinates you can perform transformation to cartesian coordinates "Polar" -> "Cartesian", because they're built-in in Mathematica, but not with user defined coordinates, which is the case in this question. I'm not sure, if ContourPlot supports user defined coordinates

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The coordinate system chosen here are the so-called Boyer-Lindquist coordinates used typically for rotating black holes.