# ListContourPlot in polar coordinates

Tags: plotting, visualization

I deal with two functions `f[r,a]`, where `r` and `a` represent modulus and phase of complex number, i.e. `z=r*Exp[I*a]`.
I obtain 2D array in the following way,

```
lst=Table[Abs[f[r,a]], {a,0,2*Pi,2*Pi/100}, {r,0,1,0.01}]
```

I would like to see for which values of `a` and `r` the value of `Abs[f[r,a]]` is close to 1. To do it, I use `ListContourPlot` function and obtain

[image]

But I have a vague feeling that in my set up it is more appropriate to visualize in polar coordinates. To do it, I perform

```
values = Table[{r*Cos[a], r*Sin[a], Abs[f[r,a]},
 {a, 0, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/100}, {r, 0, 1.0, 0.01}]
```

and then `ListContourPlot` for obtained `values` array.

However, resulting plot seems wrong,

[image: fig2]

To be honest, I do not understand what did I wrong. I try to find something about `ListContourPlot` in polar coordinates but it was unsuccessful (for instance, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203867/polar-contour-plot-in-mathematica)).

Let me clarify my point of concern. For simplicity, consider the function

```
f[r_, a_] := Cos[a]/(1 + r^2).
```

Having cells evaluated, I obtain

[image]

Now, it seems correct to use `TransformField`

```
tf = TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
  f[r, a], {r, a} -> {x, y}]
```

and then use `ContourListPlot`, which results

[image]

The last two pictures are plotted for the *same* function `f` but they are different

Comment: Your `values = Table[Table[{r*Cos[a], r*Sin[a], Abs[f[r, a]}, {a, 0, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/100}, {r, 0, 1.0, 0.01}]` is syntactically incorrect. The brackets are pink in the notebook so you should be able to tell they are unmatched. Also Table[Table is unnecessary, as a single Table can already take multiple iterators at the end. The reason it's looking bad is because you need to interpolate those points into a grid for ListContourPlot. Also `Abs[f[r,a]` is missing a bracket and you need to give a definition of `f` or at least a simple example one.

Comment: This seems to work fine, using my own example `f`, so most of your issues are syntax related: ```f[r_, a_] := Cos[a]/(1 + r^2);
values = Flatten[Table[
    {r*Cos[a], r*Sin[a], Abs[f[r, a]]}
    , {a, 0, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/100}, {r, 0, 1.0, 0.01}
    ], 1];
ListContourPlot[values]```

Comment: @flinty the mentioned syntax error comes from copy-paste. I have fixed this issue. The point about interpolation is not clear for me. The very first plot was obtained without any interpolation. My point of concern is that the second plot do not correspond to polar coordinates

Comment: Yeah actually if you look at ListContourPlot's second form in the docs, you don't need to interpolate into a grid like the first form. All your need is a rank 2 list of {{x,y,z},{x,y,z},...}. Your problem was that you weren't using `Flatten[..., 1]` like in my example above to remove the extra lists.

Comment: @flinty I have implicitly assumed `Flattent` at the first level of list. If not, I would not obtain the 2nd plot from my question

Comment: ```values = Flatten[
   Table[{r*Cos[a], r*Sin[a], Abs[f[r, a]]}, {a, 0, 2*Pi, 
     2*Pi/100}, {r, 0, 1.0, 0.01}], 1];
ListContourPlot[values]``` This should work - but I cannot tell because you haven't provided your `f`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, plotting functions like `ContourPlot` work just with Cartesian coordinates but one can use the direct form of conversion `(R=Sqrt[x^2+y^2], fi=ArcTan[y,x])`.

Let's say, we have a function like `f=R^2+4 fi`:

```
f = #1^2 + 4 #2 &;

ContourPlot[f[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[y, x]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
PlotPoints -> 151]
```

[image]

This way you can draw good even the function with an evident singularity.

Comment: Thx, it was enough for me