# Faster and smoother contourplot?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, special-functions

I'm trying to make the following contour plot

```
ContourPlot[Im[InverseEllipticNomeQ[x + I y]] == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Re[InverseEllipticNomeQ[x + I y]] >= 1]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]
But the result from the default setting in Mathematica is not accurate and not smooth. I'm trying to get a better plot. I've try to set PlotPoints and Maxrecursion and Workingpresion. But that make it super slow, I've waited for a whole day and it's still not finished (for PlotPoints=400, Maxrecursion=3, and workingpresion seems to not be important).

Is there anyways I can make a smooth plot without taking too much time?

---

The figure I am trying to reproduce from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.03612.pdf :

[image]

Comment: Do you know if the function is smooth?  At a quick look it appears to oscillate very rapidly as `x->-1`.

Comment: I added an image from that paper for easy reference.

Comment: The result is much better and faster if you remove `RegionFunction` (which does not seem necessary, or could be replaced by `x^2+y^2<=1`).

Comment: @anderstood It's necessary, because I only want result that satisfies that regionfunction condition.

Comment: @Chan Does it mean that you don't want the red curves in Fig. 12?

Comment: @ I want finally. But I need that regionfunction to set different colors.

Comment: Using polar coordinates seem to help a bit: `ContourPlot[
 Im[InverseEllipticNomeQ[r*Exp[I*theta]]] == 0, {r, 0, 1}, {theta, 0, 
  Pi}]` is much faster, then you can use [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/547/plotting-an-implicit-polar-equation) to recover cartesian plot, but it's still not satisfactory.

Comment: @anderstood Yes, it's faster. But after adding the regionfunction, it becomes even slower than the cartesian case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54383/discussion-between-chan-and-anderstood).

Comment: Why did you remove the image I took the time to copy and upload?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sorry about that, I was trying to edit, and accidentally remove that, I'll add sometime later.

Comment: Oh, in that case I'll put it back.  No harm done. :-)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*(Update notice: simplified & improved speed of code)*

You could try parametrizing a curve and use symmetry to transform it into others.  That's what it looks like [the authors of the paper did (Fig. 12)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.03612.pdf).  (I'm not sure how to efficiently generate elements of $\Gamma(2)$; it's not too slow but wasteful of memory.)

```
trimends = ReplacePart[#, {1 -> {0.9, 0.1}.#[[;; 2]], -1 -> {0.1, 0.9}.#[[-2 ;;]]}] &;

u = Log[                    (* log of complex points (= τ) of base curve *)
     trimends@              (* move ends of curve in from singular points *)
      DeleteDuplicates[  
       First@Cases[
         ParametricPlot[
          ReIm[Piecewise[{{EllipticNomeQ[(1 + t)/(1 - t)],
                 t != 1}}, -1] /. t -> #] &[ (* rescale input to get even velocity *)
           Piecewise[{{0, x == 0}, {Exp[-2/x]/Exp[-4]/2, 
              0 < x < 1/2}, {1 - Exp[-2/(1 - x)]/Exp[-4]/2, 
              1/2 <= x < 1}, {1, x == 1}}]],
          {x, 0, 1},
          PlotPoints -> 3, PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 200],
         Line[p_] :> p, Infinity]].{1, I}]/(I Pi);

lfx[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}][z_] := (a z + b)/(c z + d);   (* linear fractional transform *)
arraydet = #[[1, 1]] #[[2, 2]] - #[[1, 2]] #[[2, 1]] &; (* det @ transposed list of mats *)
g2 = Pick[Transpose[#, {2, 3, 1}], arraydet[#], 1] &[   (* some elements of Γ(2) *)
    IdentityMatrix[2] + Transpose[2 Tuples[Range[-20, 20], {2, 2}], {3, 1, 2}]
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming
g2 // Length
zz =   (* images of t under g2 -- to delete equivalent transformations *)
 # /. c_?NumericQ + e_ :> Mod[c, 2] + e & /@ (Apart[lfx[#]@t] & /@ g2) // DeleteDuplicates;
zz // Length
(*
  {0.217569, Null}
  2730
  703
*)
blue = Graphics[{Darker@Blue,
  Line@Table[ReIm[Exp[I Pi z /. t -> u]], {z, zz}]
  }, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 1.02]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

*Update 2:*
For those who might want to reproduce [the whole thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15IXq.png):

```
tt = {{1, 1}, {0, 1}};
ss = {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}};
red = Graphics[{Darker@Red,
    Line@Table[ReIm[Exp[I Pi lfx[ss]@z /. t -> u]], {z, zz}]
    }, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 1.02];
gray = Graphics[{Gray,
    Line@Table[ReIm[Exp[I Pi lfx[tt.ss]@z /. t -> u]], {z, zz}]
    }, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 1.02];
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> *Image for `g2` computed with  `Range[-60, 60]` (takes several GB, 100 sec.).*

Comment: That last image would look a lot better rasterized at `ImageSize->1800` and then downsampled with `ImageResize[%, 600]`.

Comment: Hi Michael, can I know your real name so that if I use this plot I can acknowledge you?

Comment: The elliptic nome is a built-in function, so you can replace `Exp[I Pi tau[(1 + t)/(1 - t)]]` with `EllipticNomeQ[(1 + t)/(1 - t)]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. Amusingly embarrassing: I think I saw it on the command completion list but assumed it was a `True`/`False` function because of the `Q` at the end.  I didn't stop and think about it at all.

Comment: "assumed it was a `True`/`False` function because of the `Q` at the end" - heh, makes for a nice trivia question: "which of these *Mathematica* functions are not used for expression testing?" :D

Answer (score 4):

```
ContourPlot[Im[InverseEllipticNomeQ[x + I y]] == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Re[InverseEllipticNomeQ[x + I y]] >= 1],MaxRecursion->4] // AbsoluteTiming
```

This makes the plot a lot smoother, but you probably need to use an even higher recursion limit (5). The problem is: it already takes an hour on my machine (which is a bit slower than yours) - it just took a lot of RAM (1.5 GB-2GB) [image: Refined Plot - MaxRecursion -> 4]

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is just a set of hypocycloids:

```
Clear[arc]
arc[ϕ1_,ϕ2_,θ_] := 
 Module[{ϕ = ϕ2 - ϕ1, ω = θ - ϕ1, r, x, y, a},
  r = ϕ/(2 π);
  {x, y} = If[0 < ω < ϕ, {(1 - r) Cos[ω] + r Cos[(1 - r)/r ω], 
           (1 - r) Sin[ω] - r Sin[(1 - r)/r ω]}, {0, 0}];
  a = {x Cos[ϕ1] - y Sin[ϕ1], x Sin[ϕ1] + y Cos[ϕ1]};
  If[Norm[a] == 0, a = {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}];
  a
  ]
```

Let us now plot a subset of curves:

```
nmx = 12;

gr[0] = ParametricPlot[{arc[0,π, θ]}, {θ, 0, 2π}, PlotStyle -> Red,RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1 && x < 0]];
gr[1] = ParametricPlot[{arc[0,π, θ]}, {θ, 0, 2π}, PlotStyle -> Gray,RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1 && x > 0]];

gr[2] = ParametricPlot[Table[arc[π -π/i, π - π/(i + 1), θ], {i,nmx}],{θ, 0, 2 π}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1],PlotStyle -> Gray];
gr[3] = ParametricPlot[Table[arc[π + π/(i + 1), π + π/i,θ], {i,nmx}],{θ, 0, 2 π}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1],PlotStyle -> Gray];

gr[4] = ParametricPlot[Table[arc[π/(i + 1), π/i, θ], {i, nmx}], {θ, 0, 2π}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1],PlotStyle -> Red];
gr[5] = ParametricPlot[Table[arc[ 2 π - π/i, 2 π - π /(i + 1), θ], {i, nmx}], {θ, 0, 2π}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1], PlotStyle -> Red];

gr[6] = ParametricPlot[Table[arc[ 0, π/(i + 2), θ], {i, 1, nmx, 2}], {θ,0, 2 π}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1]];
gr[7] = ParametricPlot[Table[arc[ 2 π - π/(i + 2), 2 π, θ], {i, 1, nmx,2}], {θ, 0, 2 π}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1]];
gr[8] = ParametricPlot[Table[arc[π -π/(i + 2),π, θ], {i, 1, nmx, 2}], {θ, 0, 2 π},RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1]];
gr[9] = ParametricPlot[Table[arc[π, π + π/(i + 2),θ], {i, 1, nmx, 2}], {θ, 0, 2π}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1]];
gr[10] = ParametricPlot[Table[arc[ 0, π/(i + 2), θ], {i, 2, nmx, 2}], {θ,0, 2 π}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1],PlotStyle -> Gray];
gr[11] = ParametricPlot[Table[arc[ 2 π - π/(i + 2), 2 π,θ], {i, 2, nmx,2}], {θ, 0, 2 π},RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1],PlotStyle -> Gray];
gr[12] = ParametricPlot[Table[arc[π - π/(i + 2), π, θ], {i, 2, nmx, 2}], {θ, 0, 2 π},RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1],PlotStyle -> Red];
gr[13] = ParametricPlot[Table[arc[π, π + π/(i + 2),θ], {i, 2, nmx, 2}], {θ, 0, 2 π},RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, x^2 + y^2 < 1],PlotStyle -> Red];

gr[14] = ParametricPlot[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {θ, 0, 2 π}];
```

Combining together we obtain:

```
Show[Table[gr[i], {i, 0, 14}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be quite the same thing, e.g. the curved contours in the middle are missing?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The idea was to show that the accumulation points on $|z|=1$ are rational points $\frac{p}{q}\pi$ and demonstrate a connection between them in a simple way. One can lay over mine and Michael E2's solution to verify that this is correct.

Comment: I got a number of `Set::shape: ... are not the same shape. >>` messages and no usable output when I tried to run this code.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry, will correct asap. I probably mistyped something while manually formatting the code for nicer view.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Indeed, comma was missing. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Pardon me for yet another "complaint" but this is still not working for me; I think you forgot to define `nmx`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a demo of how to color the lines after the fact, without using that expensive `RegionFunction`.  I also make use of symmetry and only scan one quadrant:

```
p = Normal@
    ContourPlot[
     Im[InverseEllipticNomeQ[x + I y]] == 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
     RegionFunction -> (Norm[{##}] & < 1)]; // AbsoluteTiming
lines = Cases[ p , Line[__], Infinity];
Graphics[{
    MapAt[{1, 1} # & /@ # &, #, {1}], 
    MapAt[{-1, 1} # & /@ # &, #, {1}], 
    MapAt[{-1, -1} # & /@ # &, #, {1}], 
    MapAt[{1, -1} # & /@ # &, #, {1}]} & /@ (Line[#[[1]], 
      VertexColors -> (If[TrueQ[# >= 1], Red, White] &@
           Re[InverseEllipticNomeQ[#[[1]] + 
              I #[[2]]]] & /@ #[[1]])] & /@ lines)]
```

[image]

you should be able to improve the quality of this if you use `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` options.